# Understanding Tensorflow maxpooling

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, max-pooling

I am unable to understand why tensorflow maxpooling with my parameters.

When performed a maxpool with `ksize=2` and `strides=2` i get the following output with both `padding SAME` and `padding VALID`

```
input :  (?, 28, 28, 1)
conv2d_out :  (?, 28, 28, 32)
maxpool2d_out :  (?, 14, 14, 32)
```

But when I try to perfrom maxpool with `ksize=3` and `strides=1`, I get the following output:

```
input :  (?, 28, 28, 1)
conv2d_out :  (?, 28, 28, 32)
maxpool2d_out :  (?, 28, 28, 32) PADDING SAME
maxpool2d_out :  (?, 26, 26, 32) PADDING VALID
```

maxpool with `ksize=2` and `strides=2` using `padding SAME` should have produced the output `maxpool2d_out :  (?, 28, 28, 32)`

Is there something I missed out on how max pooling with padding works?

`**CODE**==`[*python_*](http://codepad.org/IwxshYr1)

Comment: please share the code

Comment: http://codepad.org/IwxshYr1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw in your code you use `padding=SAME`. When using the **SAME** paddding and `strides=1`, the input and output size are the same. Why do you think the tensorflow implementation is wrong?

**Update:** 
According to [tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/nn/convolution):

**Using SAME padding**

```
out_height = ceil(float(in_height) / float(strides[1]))
out_width  = ceil(float(in_width) / float(strides[2]))
```

- It is 28/1=28 when k=3 and stride=1
- It is 28/2= 14 when k=2 and stride =2

**Using VALID padding**

```
out_height = ceil(float(in_height - filter_height + 1) / float(strides[1]))
out_width  = ceil(float(in_width - filter_width + 1) / float(strides[2]))
```

- It is celing((28-3+1)/1)= 26 when k=3, stride =1
- It is ceiling((28-2+1)/2)= 14 when k=2, stride=2

As you can see, because of the ceiling function, your result happens to be the same using different PADDING configuration

Comment: Please ignore. Seems some beats me on this. :-)

Comment: I was trying to figure that out. This point did strike me but `VALID` and `SAME` yield the same output for `ksize=2 stride=2`. How??

Answer (score 1):

You're using `padding='SAME'`, this means that your output will be padded with zeros in order to have the same size of the input.

If you change `padding` to `VALID` then the output is not padded with zeros and the pooling operation will work as you expect.

Comment: I was trying to figure that out. This point did strike me but `VALID` same `SAME` yield the same output for `ksize=2 stride=2`. How??

Comment: sorry i updated the question. Thankyou for the answer. Guess I need to read the document carefully again.